# Select null record through the query string params?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my javascript file which is filtering the records from my table in rails.

```
var dict = {
  'columns' : {
    'Sun': 5,
    'Rain': [1,2,3]
  }
}
```

which returns

```
"columns%5BSun%5D=5&columns%5BRain%5D%5B%5D=1&columns%5BRain%5D%5B%5D=2&columns%5BRain%5D%5B%5D=3"
```

The above code works however it missing a record where the `Rain is null`.

Is there anyway that I can get that `null` record like the following in javascript?

```
var dict = {
  'columns' : {
    'Sun': 5,
    'Rain': [1,2,3,null]
  }
}
```

which returns

```
"columns%5BSun%5D=5&columns%5BRain%5D%5B%5D=1&columns%5BRain%5D%5B%5D=2&columns%5BRain%5D%5B%5D=3&columns%5BRain%5D%5B3%5D="
```

The above code is not working.

I want to pass 'null' to Rails to get all `NULL` records back from `ActiveRecord`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify your question, you want to pass 'null' to Rails to get all NULL records back from ActiveRecord?

Comment: Yes @christian-g Thanks

Comment: Why dont u just check with `""` in your ruby code. You will get array of `Rain` like `["1","2","3",""]`, so you can simply take empty as `nil` in ruby

Comment: Thanks @harrybomrah . Any example in ruby would be great to follow.

Comment: @Sri please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you want

```
columns = params[:columns]
rain = columns[:Rain]
rain.each do |r|
    if r.empty?
        YourModel.where(:field => nil) # this query can differ
    else
        YourModel.where(:field => r.to_i) # this query can differ
    end
end
```

Comment: No problem :) Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript Object and add it in array. after that convert into json object.

```
var Rain = new Array();
obj = new Object();
obj.value = 1;
Rain[0] = obj;
obj = new Object();
obj.value = 2;
Rain[1] = obj;
obj = new Object();
obj.value = null;
Rain[2] = obj;
dict = {
 'columns' : {
 'Sun': 5,
 'Rain': Rain
 }
}
JSON.stringify(dict);
//For converting to Query string use as follows 
var result = $.param(dict);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But how does it gonna help to construct the query string?

Comment: @Sri Please check I have update the code for query string.

Comment: Sorry mate. I got $.param().. is not a function and you are missing closing hash as well.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But it returns the same result what I have tried in my question. @HarryBomrah's answer worked.